# How to display data in Repeater using asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have to display data from database like in a [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxaMjOdGr5C9TnJFZEpGR2RtYm8/view?usp=sharing)  in asp.net webforms. I tried to do it through Repeater ([second picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxaMjOdGr5C9cHQ4QUt0RW4xa1E/view?usp=sharing)):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnection %>" SelectCommand="DataSelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>                    
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptStudents" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" OnItemDataBound="rptStudents_ItemDataBound">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Table runat="server">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell>Course</asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>Grade</asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:Table>                                                         
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Table ID="tbStudents" runat="server">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell ID="tcStudent" runat="server" ColumnSpan="2" Visible="true">
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StudentName") %>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseName") %>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Grade") %>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:Table>                            
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

What can be added to **rptStudents_ItemDataBound** or there is another function that can be used? By default **tcStudent** is visible but if **tcStudent.Visible = false;** then all students names not displayed. But how to make that student's name is displayed only once?

```
protected void rptStudents_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell tcStudent = (TableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tcStudent");
        tcStudent.Visible = false;            
    }
```

I just started to learn asp.net webforms, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this is a school project. I dont want to give you the complete solution,  but will try to point you in the right direction.  Look at the data that you are getting from database, repeater is simply displaying the data that you are getting from database.

Answer (score 0):

A repeater is an option, but if you simply want a grid, consider using a GridView. You can then alter the formatting in the tags to make the header style and alternating row style. Far less complex.

NOTE: Good developers are lazy! (I mean efficient, of course?)